# Show multiline Flow errors in Vim status line?

Tags: vim, eslint, flowtype, neovim, vim-airline

I'm using NVIM v0.2.2 with `'w0rp/ale'` configured to lint for Flow errors. I see a single line error message in the status bar. However, Flow errors tend to be multiline errors. How can I configure my editor to display the full multiline Flow error?

Here's what I see:
[image]

Here is my `nvim/init.vim` file:

```
" Install Vim Plug if not installed
if empty(glob('~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
    \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
endif

call plug#begin()

Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plug 'rking/ag.vim'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'prettier/vim-prettier', { 'do': 'yarn install' }
Plug 'rakr/vim-one'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'w0rp/ale'

call plug#end()

let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
let g:javascript_plugin_flow = 1
let g:ag_working_path_mode="r"
let g:prettier#config#bracket_spacing = 'true'
let g:prettier#config#jsx_bracket_same_line = 'false'
let g:prettier#config#arrow_parens = 'avoid'
let g:prettier#config#trailing_comma = 'none'
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 0

if &listchars ==# 'eol:$'
  set listchars=tab:>\ ,trail:-,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:+
endif

set number

"Credit joshdick
"Use 24-bit (true-color) mode in Vim/Neovim when outside tmux.
"If you're using tmux version 2.2 or later, you can remove the outermost $TMUX check and use tmux's 24-bit color support
"(see < http://sunaku.github.io/tmux-24bit-color.html#usage > for more information.)
if (empty($TMUX))
  if (has("nvim"))
  "For Neovim 0.1.3 and 0.1.4 < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/2198 >
  let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1
  endif
  "For Neovim > 0.1.5 and Vim > patch 7.4.1799 < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/61be73bb0f965a895bfb064ea3e55476ac175162 >
  "Based on Vim patch 7.4.1770 (`guicolors` option) < https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8a633e3427b47286869aa4b96f2bfc1fe65b25cd >
  " < https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Following-HEAD#20160511 >
  if (has("termguicolors"))
    set termguicolors
  endif
endif
set background=dark " for the dark version
" set background=light " for the light version
set laststatus=2
colorscheme one
let g:lightline = {
      \ 'colorscheme': 'one',
      \ 'active': {
      \   'left': [ [ 'mode', 'paste' ],
      \             [ 'gitbranch', 'readonly', 'filename', 'modified' ] ],
      \ },
      \ 'component_function': {
      \   'gitbranch': 'fugitive#head'
      \ },
      \ }

" Asynchronous Lint Engine (ALE)
" Limit linters used for JavaScript.
let g:ale_linters = {
\  'javascript': ['flow']
\}
highlight clear ALEErrorSign " otherwise uses error bg color (typically red)
highlight clear ALEWarningSign " otherwise uses error bg color (typically red)
let g:ale_sign_error = 'X' " could use emoji
let g:ale_sign_warning = '?' " could use emoji
let g:ale_statusline_format = ['X %d', '? %d', '']
" %linter% is the name of the linter that provided the message
" %s is the error or warning message
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%linter% says %s'
" Map keys to navigate between lines with errors and warnings.
nnoremap <leader>an :ALENextWrap<cr>
nnoremap <leader>ap :ALEPreviousWrap<cr>
```

Comment: I don't have a solution for this, but seems to be a common problem with lint/flow UI's in multiple editors.  Lint errors are often related to a specific line/column, and so that's how the UI's have been conceived.  Flow errors are multi line largely to help illustrate the context for the error, especially as the context can extend over two or more lines.  I tend to just have a terminal window open elsewhere so that I can run flow from the command line to see the multiline error and properly see the context, when I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ale supports opening a list window with linting errors, see `:help g:ale_open_list`.

Note that you may need something like

```
autocmd FileType qf setlocal wrap
```

to get long lines to wrap in a quickfix window.